# Transparent background from png to jpg in imagemagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I made some png images into round corner in image magick .But when I tried to make all the png images into JPG format, the round corner background is converting into white and I want the round corner should be in transparent.I am using these commands to make them transparent but not getting any good results.

```
1. convert image.png -background white -flatten -alpha off image.jpg
2. convert image.png -background none -flatten -alpha off image.jpg
```

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jpgs cannot be transparent, only gifs and pngs (ok svgs too) so it will fill with white pixels in for transparent areas.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you cannot do it.  JPEG format simply does not support transparency.  You have to leave the images in PNG format (or conver them to GIF - but why would you do that?)

Answer (score 1):

JPG does not support transparency in any form whatsoever. If you want transparency, you'll have to use PNG.